# Ocaml Custom Data types

Tags: ocaml

```
type expr =
    | Plus of expr * expr        (* a + b *)
    | Minus of expr * expr       (* a - b *)
    | Times of expr * expr       (* a * b *)
    | Divide of expr * expr      (* a / b *)
    | Var of string              (* "x", "y", etc. *)
```

Having this type "expr" I wanted to know how can I work with a customizable number of variables depending on my needs, in this case, we know that Plus is (Expr * Expr) but what if I want to do to do : ( a + b + c) or (a * b * c), is it possible? I got this example at https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html

Comment: How about this? `Plus (Var "c", Plus (Var "a", Var "b"))`...

Comment: [Try OCaml Online](https://try.ocamlpro.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Since `+` is a binary operation, the usual representation of `a + b + c` is this:

```
Plus (Plus (Var "a", Var "b"), Var "c")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if instead of being binary operators are for example logical operators, having (a /\ b /\ c) is different from having like (      a /\ (b /\ c) , in this case, that solution you wrote above wouldn't work. Is there any other option in this case?

Comment: Boolean "and" is another binary operator--usually languages define `a /\ b  /\ c` as meaning `(a  /\  b)  /\  c` (left associative). But you can have operators with arbitrary arity if you like: you would have `expr list` rather than `expr * expr` in your type definition.

Comment: Hm okok i got it, so i can only do what i wanted with a list i that it? No other way to do it in a case i cant really change the type definition?

Comment: A type defines a set of structures. You can't change the set without changing the type definition. In the current definition, you have binary trees with `Var s` at the leaves. That's all. As a side comment, you can look at a language processing program (such as the OCaml compiler) and  you'll see that these binary trees are good enough to make a whole compiler :-)